# Amazon DynamoDB LastEvaluatedKey pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

is there a specific pattern for the **lastEvaluatedKey** generated by queries in DynamoDB?

For example, I have this lastEvaluatedKey generated by my application:

```
Z29xDjto3TZfcGsrLVLOXnfCdekB5QQ02jCxsocEVI/+Pkt1X8ypKigJvw+ZdlpGpNtp0TvyvfLVx/xV4B8RlqF0tl9zFNJMhhxgcdnjBVKU9+PSFRDdWY7eS84WEMPodKpefliBJGiXznawkZorBQ==
```

What special characters do I expect to be used on this lastEvaluatedKey and do all lastEvaluatedKey end on "=="?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS DynamoDB docs say the following about `LastEvaluatedKey`

> The primary key of the item where the operation stopped, inclusive of the previous result set. Use this value to start a new operation, excluding this value in the new request.
>
> If LastEvaluatedKey is empty, then the "last page" of results has been processed and there is no more data to be retrieved.
>
> If LastEvaluatedKey is not empty, it does not necessarily mean that there is more data in the result set. The only way to know when you have reached the end of the result set is when LastEvaluatedKey is empty.

So as I understand it, it's hashed value of your primary key (or just the partition/hash key?). AFAIK, AWS does not publicly share their hashing algorithm, so basically you cannot expect any specific pattern on it. Also it might change in some future versions. I would advice against using for anything other than what is documented.